# Instructions to navigate Newark airport: terminal change after customs

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, ewr

I will arrive at Newark terminal C on an international flight (United), go through customs and immigration (I am a foreign national with visitor visa B-2), and then have to board another plane on terminal A (also United). I will have one checked bag, which I believe I will have to collect after going through immigration but before going through customs check. These are some questions that I have:

1. After customs, do I re-check my bag at the United desk in terminal C itself? Or do I carry the bag to terminal A and check it there?
2. After customs, do I take the AirTrain to terminal A?
3. After arriving at terminal A, do I have to go through security check before boarding my flight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have purchased a single ticket for this trip and are not combining two separate tickets. Let me know if this is not the case.

You've pretty much got it. You'll arrive at Newark and be directed to the immigration and customs area. After going through immigration, you'll be in the baggage claim area (TV monitors will tell you which baggage claim to use). Pickup your bag and take it out through customs. Then drop the bag with the staff immediately outside the customs area, ride AirTrain to the correct terminal, go through TSA airport security, and proceed to your gate.

To answer your questions directly:

1. Just after you exit the customs area, there will be airline staff operating a bag drop. Simply give them you're checked bag, and they will re-check it for you.
2. Yes. Get on the AirTrain (there are signs to direct you) and take it between terminals. It's a good idea to double-check the gate assignment for your flight first, as flights are sometimes moved around.
3. Yes. You'll be able to skip the ticket counter, as you should already have your boarding pass and be checked-in. You'll go through a security checkpoint before you are allowed into the departure area in Terminal A.

Comment: Yes, I have purchased a single ticket for this trip, and not combining two separate tickets. Great answer.